# Вывод трех массивов в html таблицу с js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть 3 массива которые нужно передать в таблицу, первый это двумерный массив, другие одномерные.

```
    let table = document.createElement("TABLE")
    let tableBody = document.createElement("TBODY")
    table.appendChild(tableBody)

    let up = [
        [17, 20, 29, 26, 25],
        [3, 4, 5, 15, 24],
        [19, 2, 22, 4, 13],
        [20, 27, 1, 17, 19]]

    let i = [15,15,15,15]
    let j = [11,11,11,11,16]

    // n x m размер двумерного массива, после последней 
    // строки нужно вывести одномерный массив внутри таблицы,
    // после последнего столбца нужно вывести второй одномерный массив

    for (let row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        let tr = document.createElement("TR")
        tableBody.appendChild(tr)
        for (let col = 0; col < m; col++) {
            let td = document.createElement("TD")
            td.innerHTML = up[row][col]
            if (up[row][col] != 0) {
                td.innerHTML = up[row][col]
            }
            tr.appendChild(td)
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table)
    // Результат должен быть
    // 17 20 29 26 25 15
    // 3  4  5  15 24 15
    // 19 2  22 4  13 15
    // 20 27 1  17 19 15
    // 11 11 11 11 16
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели примеры массивов, и показали как из них должна формироваться таблица, чтобы было понятнее в чем у вас проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего объединить массивы в один двумерный, после чего уже вывести его таблицей.

```js
let table = document.createElement("TABLE")
let tableBody = document.createElement("TBODY")
table.appendChild(tableBody)

let up = [
  [17, 20, 29, 26, 25],
  [3, 4, 5, 15, 24],
  [19, 2, 22, 4, 13],
  [20, 27, 1, 17, 19]
]

let rigth = [15, 15, 15, 15]
let down = [11, 11, 11, 11, 16]

for (let i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
  up[i].push(rigth[i]);
}
up.push(down);

for (let i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement("TR")
  tableBody.appendChild(tr); {
    for (let j = 0; j < up[i].length; j++) {
      let td = document.createElement("TD")
      td.innerHTML = up[i][j];
      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(table)
// Результат должен быть
// 17 20 29 26 25 15
// 3  4  5  15 24 15
// 19 2  22 4  13 15
// 20 27 1  17 19 15
// 11 11 11 11 16
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```